# 80s movie involving friendly, flying aliens that were light creatures (not Cocoon)

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The aliens were friendly and flew. In the end, they were saying goodbye, like at a hospital maybe. They were light creatures; the graphics were bad, they looked hand-drawn, kind of. It’s not *[Cocoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoon_(film))* (1985), but kinda has the same vibe. This has been stuck in my head for years and I cannot find it. Help please!

Comment: Hi. Did you actually watch this in the '80s or more recently? If more recently, then when? Also, did the film feature any alien technology such as a spaceship? And do you recall any locations that were shown in the film, aside from the hospital you mentioned?

Comment: Also, you said that it's not _Cocoon_ (1985), but have you ruled out the sequel, _[Cocoon: The Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoon:_The_Return)_ (1988)?

Comment: The other film around the same time that had the similar "aliens help old folk" theme was *Batteries Not Included*.

Comment: Any chance that you are remembering James cameron's movie "The Abyss", from 1989? The glowing underwater aliens in this movie seemed to fly on stingray-like wings.